# Memory Management in C# Or VB.net released the memory on form close

Tags: c#

I am facing a problem with memory management using an MDI parent form and Child form in my project. When I close the child form the memory which allocated for that form is not released - how can I do this?

Comment: Memory allocated to form is not release. What you mean by this ? What error you are getting ? Are you using any external unmanaged resources on form ? if yes then use Dispose() method of that resource.

Comment: One of the possible outcome is that there is no problem with your code. In a garbage collected environment as .net is, memory is released to OS only when GC thinks it's time for releasing it. Consider this possibility when you are talking about "memory not released"

Answer (score 1):

In normal circumstances the framework (more specifically; the garbage collector) will deal with this.

You could speed things up by calling `Dispose` on all disposables.

As it come to memory cleanup: in general make sure you do the following:

- remove all references to an object if you're done with it. Just closing a window is insufficient if you have a reference to it somewhere; possibly in a list (since MDI) or in a object reference (in that case call `Dispose` and set it to `null`)
- Cleanup unmanaged code explicitly: use `IDispose` interface.
- Let the garbage collector handle it, your code shouldn't rely on things like `GC.Collect()`.